# WCF Service BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services

I have just created a wcf service library and am using a simple console application to connect to it. However the moment I start my console application, the wcf service host opens and shows this error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\uop\source\repos\WPF\APPONE\APPONE.Service\bin\x86\Debug\APPONE.Service.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
File name: 'file:///C:\Users\amosa\source\repos\WPF\APPONE\APPONE.Service\bin\x86\Debug\APPONE.Service.dll'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.LoadServiceAssembly(String svcAssemblyPath)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

I have made sure that all my apps are running x86.

I tried to see if its an issue in my program but it doesn't even reach the first debugging point in my program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Step 1: Create a URI to serve as the base address.
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8733/APPONE/");

    // Step 2: Create a ServiceHost instance.
    ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(DocumentType), baseAddress);

    try
    {
        selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDocumentType), new WSHttpBinding(), "DocumentType");
        // Step 4: Enable metadata exchange.
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        // Step 5: Start the service.
        selfHost.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");

        // Close the ServiceHost to stop the service.
        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to terminate the service.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
        selfHost.Close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", e.Message);
        selfHost.Abort();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description,I did the test.First,you need to set the platform target value to "Any CPU":

[image]

Then build your project into an executable and run it as an administrator:

[image]

In addition,the .Net framework I use is 4.7.2.In fact,if you use x86 to debug in VS,you will get the above errors,you directly build the project into an executable file and then run it as an administrator,it is OK.